# Finding Outliers In SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am very new to SQL and have my data in an Access database (~50k rows) with the following structure

```
State  Year  Date    Price
CA     2012  1/2/13  5.00
NY     2013  1/2/13  6.00
NY     2013  1/7/13  7.00
```

A (State, Year) pair, though held in different columns here, represent a vintage (like a wine). So we talk about how the price of "CA 2012" moves throughout the year.

Because some of our data is entered manually into this database, there is opportunity for error. We would like to write a query that flags any suspicious entries for further review.

I have read many different questions and threads on the subject but have not found anything that addresses my main concern of how to find local outliers - the price can move up and down so prices that may be okay for some date range may be an outlier earlier in the year

Update: I chunked my data into buckets of months so finding local outliers might be easier as a result of that. I'm still looking for good outlier detection methods I can implement in SQL.

Comment: how do you intend to calculate your outliers, exactly?

Comment: With TOP to determine x number of highest values in you column price? Or min / max price?

Comment: I don't have any particular method in mind. Any (even naive) simple implementation would work great so I can at least start playing around with it.

Comment: For example: `select top 10 Price, State, Year from table_name order by Price desc` To select the 10 highest prices from you table.

Comment: I don't really understand where you are going with the "select top" route since we may have data points like this: (1, 2, 3, 15, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15).

So 15 is an outlier in the earlier part, but not later.

Comment: Exactly the point of the first comment. How would you like to calculate the outlier?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, because you are basically looking for a statical technique. And with a time component that would call for something with a moving average type of analysis. Not simply selecting everything below or above the xth percentile. My guess would be to try a statical program.

Comment: Ok.. like I said, I don't have a specific implementation since I do not know what would typically be easy to do in SQL. 

A general and bad method might be look at points within (+/-) 1 week of selected date. Calculate average, say anything that is > some % away from that is an outlier.

EDIT: Thanks, it could be that this is not easy to do in SQL and could be better served with something more specialized.

Comment: Maybe you could look at making input control in MS ACCESS so you get an upfront check if a value deviates from the previous entry. For example, if a entry is more than 10 % of then user will get an alert screen (Asking if the entered value is correct). Probably something you could do with a macro. Rubbish in rubbish out.

Comment: Another option would be to calculate the difference between the current and the previous entry.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of point 1 (`most databases...`), as your table looks decently set up.  Even data entered automatically has opportunity for error - anything with pricing was entered manually at _some_ point.  What version of Access/backing db?  Later versions have better ways to detect certain things...

Comment: Good points, I have a sort of implementation going that has already caught a few errors, am now just looking for any sort of guidance on outlier detection techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes simple is best- No need for an intro to statistics yet.  I would recommend starting with simple grouping.  Within that function you can Average, get the minimum, the Maximum and other useful bits of data.  Here are a couple of examples to get you started:

```
    SELECT Table1.State, Table1.Yr, Count(Table1.Price) AS CountOfPrice, Min(Table1.Price) AS MinOfPrice, Max(Table1.Price) AS MaxOfPrice, Avg(Table1.Price) AS AvgOfPrice
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.State, Table1.Yr;
```

Or (in case you want month data included)

```
    SELECT Table1.State, Table1.Yr, Month([Dt]) AS Mnth, Count(Table1.Price) AS CountOfPrice, Min(Table1.Price) AS MinOfPrice, Max(Table1.Price) AS MaxOfPrice
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.State, Table1.Yr, Month([Dt]);
```

Obviously you'll need to modify the table and field names (Just so you know though- 'Year' and 'Date' are both reserved words and best not used for field names.)

Comment: Thank you, this reply was super helpful. The GROUP BY command works really well for me. For each (State, Vintage) pair I chunked the values into buckets of months and computed the Average, Min, and Max as you suggested.

Right now I'm implementing my naive method, which is taking the average and having some +/- percentage tolerance for errors, and if the min or max is outside of that range then I flag it.

Is there anything simple that might be better?

Comment: Not really, at least none that leap to mind. What you worked up should work fine. When you start delving into statistics things get pretty complex pretty quickly. For instance; in the group by method there is no 'weighting' of data and that is almost always a need in stats.  It just looked like you wanted something to get you started- from there you need to research specifics.  Statistics is a big field, take it in small bites if you can.